# DWORD and unsigned int

Tags: c++, windows

I'm getting this error and can't correct it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'DWORD *' to 'unsigned int'
IntelliSense: a value of type "DWORD *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned int"

```
using namespace std;
typedef vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> tFoundFilesVector;
std::wstring LastWriteTime;  
int getFileList(wstring filespec, tFoundFilesVector &foundFiles)
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE h;
int validResult=true;

int numFoundFiles = 0;
h = FindFirstFile(filespec.c_str(), &findData);

if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 0;

while (validResult)
{
    numFoundFiles++;
    foundFiles.push_back(findData);
    validResult = FindNextFile(h, &findData);
}
return numFoundFiles;
}

void showFileAge(tFoundFilesVector &fileList)
{
    unsigned int fileTime,curTime, age;
    tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter;
FILETIME ftNow;
__int64 nFileSize;
    LARGE_INTEGER li;    
li.LowPart = ftNow.dwLowDateTime;
li.HighPart = ftNow.dwHighDateTime;

CoFileTimeNow(&ftNow);
    curTime = ((_int64) &ftNow.dwHighDateTime << 32) + &ftNow.dwLowDateTime;

    for (iter=fileList.begin(); iter<fileList.end(); iter++)
    {
    fileTime = ((_int64)iter->ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime << 32) + iter-                       >ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime;

    age = curTime - fileTime;

    cout << "FILE: '" << iter->cFileName << "', AGE: " << (INT64)age/10000000UL << " seconds" <<     endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
string fileSpec = "*.*";
tFoundFilesVector foundFiles;
tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter;

int foundCount = 0;

getFileList(L"*.c??", foundFiles);
getFileList(L"*.h", foundFiles);

foundCount = foundFiles.size();
if (foundCount)
{
    cout << "Found "<<foundCount<<" matching files.\n";
    showFileAge(foundFiles);
}
return 0;
}
```

Its on this line.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here:

```
curTime = ((_int64) &ftNow.dwHighDateTime << 32) + &ftNow.dwLowDateTime;
```

`dwHighDateTime` and `dwLowDateTime` are already of type `int`. Yet you are taking the address of them.  Therefore the assignment to `curTime` becomes pointer to int.

What you want is this:

```
curTime = ((_int64) ftNow.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ftNow.dwLowDateTime;
```

Second Issue:

`curTime` and `fileTime` are only 32-bits. You need to make them 64-bit integers.

Comment: Thank you!!!! First issue solved! How can I make those 64-bit integers, never had to deal with this. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `unsigned long long`. But since you're on Windows, you can just use `unsigned __int64`.